# Gnuplot: Point size variable maximum size

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to make a plot with the points variable size depending on the value of the data.

I know that the basic command is

`plot 'something.dat' u 1:2:3 w p ps variable`,

but how can I choose the maximum size of the dots?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply limit the size with a conditional in the last column of the `using` statement:

```
lim = 42
plot 'something.dat' u 1:2:($3 < lim ? $3 : lim) w p ps variable
```

Comment: Ok, as far as I understand, the line means: plot the actual value of third column if the value is less than 42, otherwise pretend it's 42.

Actually what I wanted to ask is how to increase the maximum size of the dot. If I choose `ps 1` or `ps 10` the size of the dot is always the same.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, see the question, thanks anyway cause I learned conditional plottting.

Comment: OK, I got your question wrong. In any case: Please revert your edit, add your own answer and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found out I only need to write
`scale=2.0`
`plot 'something.dat' u 1:2:(($3)*scale) w p ps variable`

and I get the points magnified by a factor 2.